# Error when generating new component in Angular 14.7.13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

When I try to create a new component in my Angular 14.7.13 app by running this code:

```
/f/JS/apps/myapp/src/app/board (main)
$ npx nx generate @nrwl/angular:component board --project=myapp --style=scss --no-interactive --verbose
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: The path provided for the component (src/app/board) does not exist under the project root (). Please make sure to provide a path that exists under the project root.
at checkPathUnderProjectRoot (F:\JS\apps\myapp\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\src\generators\component\component.js:34:15)
at F:\JS\apps\myapp\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\src\generators\component\component.js:14:9
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at F:\JS\apps\myapp\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:118:75
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.__awaiter (F:\JS\apps\myapp\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:16)
at componentGenerator (F:\JS\apps\myapp\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\src\generators\component\component.js:11:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\JS\apps\myapp\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\generate.js:250:36)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (F:\JS\apps\myapp\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:115:62)
```

I am in the folder where I want the 'board' component to be.

It makes no difference if I run it in the project root which is /f/js/apps/myapp/ as I get the same error.

This seems to be a known issue as per this thread: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/12042. See comment:

> While waiting for the fix to be published, **you can still generate the component by specifying the --project flag with the project name where the component is going to be generated**. The fix removes this requirement when a path is provided.

But I am running --project=myapp?

Can anyone tell me if they're aware of a fix for this issue, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution to this is to edit the "root" property in `angular.json`, which should be placed in the root folder of your project.

Change its line from

`"root": "",`

to

`"root": "./src",`

This will allow you to create new Components in your src/app folder.